# Unable to obtain stable firefox connection in 60 seconds (127.0.0.1:7055). When I am executing cucumber file

Tags: ruby, firefox, selenium-webdriver, cucumber

I am using Firefox version 50.0.1 and Selenium-Webdriver gem version 3.0.3. I am able to create Firefox instance but not able to proceed for further operations using script Getting unable to obtain stable firefox connection in 60 seconds (127.0.0.1:7055) error.

Can someone help me ?

Comment: Downgrade to FF 45. See here https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium/issues/835

Comment: I don't know whether it might help you but it did help me. I added the path of GeckoDriver to system paths and it resolved my problem. I'm using selenium with C# so not sure with cucumber.